# Way to have CMake run the make file for openssl before building the makefile for curl in my thirdparty libs

Tags: curl, cmake

I have thirdparty libs in my application that includes openssl and curl as well and curl is using the openssl as static libs (libssl.a, libcrypto.a)
my higher level CMakeFileLists.txt looks like as below:

```
add_subdirectory(myapp)
add_subdirectory(thirdparty/openssl)
add_subdirectory(thirdparty/libssh2)
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR ${openssl_BINARY_DIR})//I have set the openssl binary dir for curl 
add_subdirectory(thirdparty/curl)
```

When I build then CMake builds the curl first and search for openssl libs which are still not built, so it gives the below error

> Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
> system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_LIBRARIES)

**How we can execute a makefile with CMake before building the other makes?**

I have CMake 3.5 version.

Comment: This is a bad way to handle dependencies in general... have you looked into vcpkg or Conan?

Comment: I am doing this build on linux, Please help me by providing the good way to handle this.